# Postgresql return zero-length delimited error

Tags: php, laravel, postgresql, eloquent, psql

I am trying to make a connection with PostgreSQL 12 for Laravel framework. I use Laravel 5.8 version. When I try to login a user by using Laravel's Auth::attempt() method, I get the following error:

`Syntax error: 7 ERROR:  zero-length delimited identifier at or near \"\"\"\"\nLINE 1: select * from \"\".\"users\" where \"email\" = $1 limit 1\`

I am using Laravel's default database table for user data. Eveyrthing works well when using MySQL but I did not understand the reason of it when I use PgSQL. Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: The schema name is missing: you have something like `from  ""."users" where ...`

Comment: I just realized. Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Double quotes make delimited identifiers. It should not be empty string like below.

**Wrong:**

```
select * from ""."users" where "email" = $email limit 1
```

**Correct:**

Use database name

```
select * from "$databaseName"."users" where "email" = $email limit 1
```

(or)
Try without database name

```
select * from "users" where "email" = $email limit 1

User::where('email',$email)->first();
```

> Check .env and database.php settings are updated with correct database
>   name.